# ¿Cómo hacer un menu fixed que cambie sus propiedades según el offset de las secciones?

Tags: jquery, menú, function, offset

Mi pregunta mas especifica es, ¿Cómo puedo hacer que mi menú tenga varios colores, según el tope de mis secciones, pues, sé cómo hacerlo, pero no puedo hacer que vuelva a los colores que tenía anteriormente. A continuación les dejaré mi método. Al yo colocar el siguiente código, el `<nav>` debe de cambiar de color background según la sección de la página, pero no puedo hacer que cambie a los colores anteriores al volver a desplazar hacia arriba ni con `else`. Solo se queda el último cambio de color.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var altura = 200;
  var section2 = $("#section2").offset().top;
  var section3 = $("#section3").offset().top;
  var section4 = $("#section4").offset().top

  $(window).scroll(function() {

    if($(window).scrollTop() >= altura){

      $("nav").css({"margin-top": "0px"});
      $("header").css({"margin-top": "-100px"});
      $(".hero").css({"margin": "90px auto"});
      $(".hero").css({"background-color": "#D9D5CC"});
      $(".hola").css({"margin-top": "90px"});

    }else{

      $("nav").css({"margin-top": "100px"});
      $("header").css({"margin-top": "0px"});
      $(".hero").css({"margin": "200px auto"});
      $(".hero").css({"background-color": "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)"});
      $(".hola").css({"margin-top": "200px"});

    }

  });

  $(window).scroll(function() {

    if($(window).scrollTop() >= section2){

      $("nav").css({"background-color": "#F2CF63"});

    }else{

      $("nav").css({"background-color": "#57385C"});

    }

  });
  
    $(window).scroll(function() {

    if($(window).scrollTop() >= section3){

      $("nav").css({"background-color": "#F2CEF7"});

    }else{

      $("nav").css({"background-color": "#F2CF63"});

    }

  });
  
  $(window).scroll(function() {

    if($(window).scrollTop() >= section4){

      $("nav").css({"background-color": "#F22E57"});

    }else{

      $("nav").css({"background-color": "#F2CEF7"});

    }

  });

  $(".inicio").click(function() {

    $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: $("#section").offset().top} , 500);

  });

  $(".nosotros").click(function() {

    $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: $("#section2").offset().top}, 500);

  });

  $(".trabajos").click(function() {

    $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: $("#section3").offset().top}, 500);

  });

  $(".contacto").click(function() {

    $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: $("#section4").offset().top}, 500);

  });

});
```

```css
* {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: #A75265;
  z-index: 5;
  -webkit-transition: .5s;
  transition: .5s;
}

header h1 {
  color: #EC7263;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

header h4 {
  color: #FFEDBC;
  margin-top: 2px;
  display: block;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
}

nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #57385C;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 5;
  margin-top: 100px;
  -webkit-transition: .5s;
  transition: .5s;
}

nav ul {
  list-style: none;
}

nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}

nav ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #A75265;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 16px;
  padding-top: 16px;
  display: block;
  font-weight: 700;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
  color: #57385C;
  background-color: #A75265;
  font-weight: 700;
  -webkit-transition: .2s;
  transition: .2s;
}

#section {
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 150px;
  height: 900px;
  background-color: #F2F2DF;
  position: relative;
}

section h1 {
  text-align: center;
  color: rgba(217, 213, 204, 0.8);
  font-size: 70px;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin-top: 200px;
  text-shadow: 1px 4px 6px #F2F2DF, 0 0 0 #000, 1px 4px 6px #F2F2DF;
  -webkit-transition: .5s;
  transition: .5s;
}

.hero {
  width: 850px;
  height: 700px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  margin: 200px auto;
  -webkit-transition: .5s;
  transition: .5s;
}

#section2 {
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 150px;
  height: 900px;
  background-color: #5A8C81;
  position: relative;
}

#section3 {
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 150px;
  height: 900px;
  background-color: #765783;
  position: relative;
}

#section4 {
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 150px;
  height: 900px;
  background-color: #86B5A8;
  position: relative;
}


.antefooter {
  height: 90px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #B17178;
}

footer {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #36282B;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
}

footer p {
  color: #F2F2DF;
  padding-top: 45px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=divice-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <title>Miguel Rangel</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/master.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/master.js">

    </script>
  <style type="text/css">/* This is not a zero-length file! */
  </style><style type="text/css">/* This is not a zero-length file! */</style>
</head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <h1>Crawford</h1>
      <h4>Diseño</h4>
    </header>
    <nav id="nav1">
      <ul>
        <li><a class="inicio" href="#section">Inicio</a></li><li>
        <a class="nosotros" href="#section2">Nosotros</a></li><li>
        <a class="trabajos" href="#section3">Trabajos</a></li><li>
        <a class="contacto" href="#section4">Contacto</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <section id="section">
      <h1 class="hola">HOLA</h1>
      <div class="hero">

      </div>
    </section>
    <section id="section2">

    </section>
    <section id="section3">

    </section>
    <section id="section4">

    </section>
    <div class="antefooter">

    </div>
    <footer><p>Copyright (c) 2017 Copyright <strong>MIGUEL</strong> All Rights Reserved.</p></footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Deberías publicar el html para revisar. Saludos

Comment: Hola, @JorgeLondoño. Ya hice una actualización de mi código.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solo no metas la condicion `else` en tus comparaciones, el sistema asume cual es la última regla cumplida.

Toma en cuenta que solo el último valor asignado, es el que se queda como ajuste en el CSS.

Aquí te dejo el demo funcionando:

https://jsfiddle.net/L7owv17v/

Y aquí el código JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  var altura = 200;
  var section2 = $("#section2").offset().top;
  var section3 = $("#section3").offset().top;
  var section4 = $("#section4").offset().top;

  $(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() >= altura) {
      $("nav").css({"margin-top": "0px"});
      $("header").css({"margin-top": "-100px"});

      $(".hero").css({
        "margin": "90px auto",
        "background-color": "#D9D5CC",
        "margin-top": "90px"
      });
    } else {
      $("nav").css({"margin-top": "100px"});
      $("header").css({"margin-top": "0px"});
      $(".hero").css({
        "margin": "200px auto",
        "background-color": "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)",
        "margin-top": "200px"
      });
    }


    if ($(window).scrollTop() < section2) {
      $("nav").css({"background-color": "#57385C"});
    }

    if ($(window).scrollTop() >= section2) {
      $("nav").css({"background-color": "#F2CF63"});
    }

    if ($(window).scrollTop() >= section3) {
      $("nav").css({"background-color": "#F2CEF7"});
    }

    if ($(window).scrollTop() >= section4) {
      $("nav").css({"background-color": "#F22E57"});
    }
  });


  $(".inicio").click(function () {
    $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: $("#section").offset().top}, 500);
  });

  $(".nosotros").click(function () {
    $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: $("#section2").offset().top}, 500);
  });

  $(".trabajos").click(function () {
    $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: $("#section3").offset().top}, 500);
  });

  $(".contacto").click(function () {
    $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: $("#section4").offset().top}, 500);
  });
});
```

Comment: Hermoso, gracias! @elporfirio